# Find document by Object ID - Converting string to objectID

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to find documents but "_id". This is for a GET call. A variable in the url will produce a string. The string in the URL will be the documentID.

This is what I have so far

```
oid := "5c9ed92ef16b6f3380b2ddce"
    filter := bson.M{"_id": oid}
    err := db.Collection("products").FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&result)
```

Am I formatting the filter wrong? Should I be converting the string to an objectID type?

Comment: Found the answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963232/mongo-go-driver-find-a-document-by-id

Comment: ```oid, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("5c9ed92ef16b6f3380b2ddce")```